# Can't get an image from application resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, bitmap, resources

I'm trying to figure out how does the ResourceManager work. I have read a couple of articles but just don't manage to have it to work...

I have added a bitmap file to my project (right click + add new item + bitmap file).
I can see the added bitmap file into the project explorer under the correct path: WinForm1/Properties/Resources/bitmapName.png

Then I try to access the resource with :

```
var test = WinForm1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("bitmapName.png"); // I also tried "bitmapName" with no luck
```

It returns null. Have I missed anything?

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the solution:

- After you add the bitmap file, close it.
- Then in the Solution Explorer, locate your file. At the same time open **Project -> Properties -> Resources**.
- Then drag the bitmap from the Solution Explorer to the Resources Panel. It will get copied as a resource.
- Then name the resource to whatever you like (it's better you keep it the same as the filename).
- Next, in the Solution Explorer, right click on the file and in the Properties panel, set Build Action to resource.

Now you should be able to access the resource by the same method in your question:

```
var test = WinForm1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("bitmapName");
```

Note that the name you pass to `GetObject()` should be the same as the one that shows up in the Resources tab in the Properties Window.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

didn't work the way you showed Farhan.
CF attached screenshot.

Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) WpfTest.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Rat_Left.png"); 
returns null although the resource build action is set to "resource".[image]